# How to add JSON column formatting programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view

I am creating a SharePoint 365 list programmatically. For each field in the list, I am using list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml.  Once the list is created, I can go to the list settings, pick a column and format it using JSON.

Is there a way to do that in the code, so that it doesn't have to be added manually to each column that requires formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `CustomFormatter` attribute to specify your custom JSON formatting of the column like below sample code:

```
var jsonSchema = "<your-json>";

string fieldSchema = "<Field Type='Text' Name='ProjectName' StaticName='ProjectName' 
DisplayName='Project Name' CustomFormatter=" + jsonSchema + "/>";
var simpleTextField = list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(fieldSchema, true, AddFieldOptions.AddToDefaultContentType);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

or if you want to update it PnP PowerShell, you can do that as below:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url 'https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/testSiteCollection'

Set-PnPField -Identity "ProjectName" -List "Custom List" -Values @{CustomFormatter = @'
 <your json>
'@
}
```